# XML/XSD get all elements and attributes as an XML string

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xsd

Input:

```
sales
    sale
        saleid
        (elements/attributes)
```

Desired output:

```
SaleId, (elements/attributes) as one big string
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be most helpful

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Your title mentions XML and XSD but your input doesn't appear to be either. What do you mean by "an XML string"? When you say "all elements and attributes" do you perhaps mean "all distinct element and attribute names appearing in the schema"? Or perhaps "all distinct element and attribute names appearing in the instance"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you seems want :

```
SELECT n.query(N'.') AS [one big string]
FROM @xml.nodes(N'/Sales/sale') AS t(n);
```

Comment: Thank you for you help :) this was the final query (8gb xml file) DECLARE "@"xml XML;

SELECT "@xml" = CONVERT(XML, bulkcolumn, 2)
FROM
       OPENROWSET(BULK
           'LocalFilePath'
         , SINGLE_BLOB)
           AS X;

SET ARITHABORT ON;

INSERT INTO XML_EACH_RECORD ( XML_EACH_RECORD )
            SELECT P.query(N'.')
            FROM   "@"xml.nodes('/sales/sale') PropertyFeed(P);